# Fill in Missing Dates, add Default number

Tags: t-sql

Assume we have the Date table below, also assume today is the 13th January, 2012:

```
DateKey    | AvailabilityPerc  
-----------------------------
2012-01-01 | 79  
2012-01-02 | 80  
2012-01-03 | 85  
2012-01-07 | 75  
2012-01-09 | 90
```

The script should do two things:
1. Fill in the missing dates from the 1st January 2012, up to three days ago, i.e. 10th of January, 2012 (current date minus three days).
2. For only the new rown, fill in the AvailabilityPerc column with a default figure, say, 100.

The resulting table should look like this:

```
DateKey    |  AvailabilityPerc
-------------------------------
2012-01-01 | 79 
2012-01-02 | 80  
2012-01-03 | 85  
2012-01-04 | 100  
2012-01-05 | 100  
2012-01-06 | 100  
2012-01-07 | 75  
2012-01-08 | 100  
2012-01-09 | 90  
2012-01-10 | 100
```

Really appreciate any assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with temp as 
(
   select DateAdd(d, -5,GETDATE()) as d, 23 as val
   UNION
   select DateAdd(d, -3,GETDATE()), 44 as val
   UNION
   select DateAdd(d, -1,GETDATE()), 55 as val
), dates as
(
   SELECT MyDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2012'), 100 as val
   UNION ALL
   SELECT MyDate = DATEADD(D,1,MyDate), 100 as val
   from dates
   WHERE MyDate < DATEADD(D,-3,GETDATE())
)

SELECT d.MyDate, COALESCE(t.val, d.val) FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN temp t
ON Convert(varchar, d.MyDate, 101) = Convert(varchar, t.d, 101)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION  365)
```

Comment: thanks Abe. When I execute the above though it doesnt defer to the temp table entries for the val variable. it overwrites all Date records with 100 only. Also I would prefer the script to actually use my table information to create a new table with missing date and values. Any further assistance is certainly appreciated.

Comment: I think that's because of the time on the datetime.  I changed the join to use date only, try that and see if it works.

Comment: Great job Abe! One problem gone, final issue. Now the script replaces temp data instead of the val 100. However, I want to read the data directly from a table and not feed them in on the script using the 'temp' table entries. My table may b over 200 records at any point in time and I need to dynamically pull in its records to the script, instead of creating the records with the UNION function. Any further ideas. Thanks

Comment: Replace temp with your table name. Dates will need to stay

Comment: Didnt work. Dates are fine, but the static val entries, 23,44 and 55 for date today() minus 5, today() -3 and today() -1, remain in the resulting table - this should not be the case. Only values in the original table should remain the resulting table. No values should be entered through the code.

Comment: Did you replace temp like I said?  It sounds like you just added your own table in addition to temp instead of replacing temp with your table.

Comment: Abe, can't thank you enough. Table inserted and issue resolved. You are fantastic.

Comment: No problem! If you think my answer solved your problem feel free to accept it by clicking the check box at the top left of my answer